# Cómo Obtener el valor del textbox de otro jframe

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un proyecto y necesito generar textbox a partir de un for, tengo otro menú donde solicito el numero de ecuaciones y a partir de este dato construyo mis textbox pero el código que tengo no me funciona, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
public void Mostrar(){
        int NumeroDeEcuaciones= Integer.parseInt((String)new ProyectoAplication().jTextFieldNumeroDeEcuaciones.getText());
            for (int i = 0; i < NumeroDeEcuaciones; i++) {
              JTextField input = new JTextField("texto por defecto",20); 
              this.add(input);
            } 
    }
```

**Edit 1:**
El error sale en esta linea`int NumeroDeEcuaciones= Integer.parseInt((String)new ProyectoAplication().jTextFieldNumeroDeEcuaciones.getText())‌​;`

Comment: que error te sale?

Comment: int NumeroDeEcuaciones= Integer.parseInt((String)new ProyectoAplication().jTextFieldNumeroDeEcuaciones.getText()); en esta linea

Comment: verifica si NumeroDeEcuaciones es mayor que cero

Comment: ese numero de ecuaciones es un otro textfield de otro formulario lo puse publico para llamarlo en ese formulario pero es cadena lo intento convertir pero nada @rn3w

Comment: `(String)new ProyectoAplication().jTextFieldNumeroDeEcuaciones.getText()` te esta devolviendo vacio, por esa razon no puedes convertir

Comment: así lo coloco dentro de la función? @rn3w

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51098/discussion-between-rn3w-and-efrainrodc).

Answer (score 0):

tu error es `new ProyectoAplication().jTextFieldNumeroDeEcuaciones.getText();`, esta devolviendo vacio, por esa razon no puedes convertir

nunca entra a la siguiente linea:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumeroDeEcuaciones; i++) {
```

y por ende no se genera tu textbox

Comment: okey como lo soluciono?

Comment: okey como lo soluciono?  @rn3w